# How to convert string set to hiveconf variable to an object usable as part of a table name

Tags: variables, hive, hiveql

I am looking for a way to remove quotes from a `hiveconf` variable string, so that I can use it also as part of a table name:

Basicaly, I have something like

```
set sub_name = "123";

select ${hiveconf:sub_name} from table_${hiveconf:sub_name};
```

And when executing I need it to work like:

```
select "123" from table_123;
```

For that, I could run with something like:

```
set variable = "123";
set table_subname = 123;

select ${hiveconf:variable} from table_${hiveconf:table_subname};
```

Which would then work as

```
select "123" from table_123;
```

But is there some elegant way how to use just the one variable, once as a string and once as a part of the table name?

Comment: I know I could do something like: `set variable = 123;` and then `select '{hiveconf:variable}' from table_${hiveconf:variable};`, but how to go the other way round?

Comment: This is a bad example since `select 123` will work as well as `select "123"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hive> create table table_abc as select 'X' as x;
OK
x
hive> set sub_name=abc;
hive> select "${hiveconf:sub_name}" from table_${hiveconf:sub_name};
OK
_c0
abc
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to go the other way round. I.e. `set sub_name="abc"; select ${hiveconf:sub_name} from table_${hiveconf:sub_name};` where I will do something in the table_ part in order to remove the quotes

Comment: @ira - **(1)** Not going to happen **(2)** It is still cleaner than your suggested solution with 2 variables

Comment: Are you sure there is no way? Or it's that you don't know about a way to do that? For example, in shell script, this could be done. I would like to do this in hql directly though

Comment: I'm sure. Variables in Hive are nothing but text replacement mechanism. You can't process the variables content.